# Java Recursion. Counting occurrences

Tags: java, arrays, list, recursion

Please help, I am stuck on a project where I have to count the number of occurrences of a word in an array using recursion and tail recursion. (I can't use for loops. This is my method:

```
public static int getNumAppearances(myList<String> l, String word){
    int res = 0; 
    return res;
}

//-------------------------------------
// tailGetNumAppearances 
//------------------------------------- 
public static int tailGetNumAppearances(myList<String> l, String word){

    int res = 0; 

    int len = l.my_get_length();

    res = extra04(l, word, len, 0);

    //4. We return the output variable
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this is not a "do my HW for me" kind of website, try to do your tasks for your own good, and post here a question when it's more concrete. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the following recursion. If you can understand that then implement in code,

```
Count(n) = 1 + Count(n-1);
Count(1) = 1; [base case]
```

So for counting an array of size n

```
Count[1..n] = 1 + Count[2..n]
```